# SQL ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling

I have the following end of code on SQL (Oracle 19c)

```
WHERE DATE >= '20220101' AND DATE BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) AND last_day (add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) AND DATE != 'None' AND QT_MOCK_DATA IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DATE DESC'
```

ERROR:

> **ORA-01861: literal does not match format string**

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: What data type is the `DATE` column? It looks like text, but you're using date functions on it without using `TO_DATE`.

Answer (score 3):

Column name certainly isn't `date`; it is reserved word, reserved for the datatype name. So, no - you don't have that code.

Next: it seems you are storing **strings** into that column (as you're comparing it to `'None'`, which is a string). That's a bad idea - dates should be stored *as dates*. Anything else brings problems (you hit one).

Then, you're comparing that string to date values. How come? The *between* part of the code returns `date`  datatype values:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1) val1,
  2         LAST_DAY (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1)) val2
  3    FROM DUAL;

VAL1                VAL2
------------------- -------------------
01.06.2022 00:00:00 30.06.2022 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Maybe you wanted to apply the `TO_CHAR` function with appropriate format model?

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1), 'yyyymmdd') val1,
  2         TO_CHAR (LAST_DAY (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1)),
  3                  'yyyymmdd') val2
  4    FROM DUAL;

VAL1     VAL2
-------- --------
20220601 20220630

SQL>
```

Because, with it, query *returns* something.

Compare

## your code

```
SQL> WITH test (date1, qt_mock_data) AS (SELECT '20220615', 'A' FROM DUAL)
  2    SELECT *
  3      FROM test
  4     WHERE     date1 >= '20220101'
  5           AND date1 BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1)
  6                         AND LAST_DAY (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1))
  7           AND date1 != 'None'
  8           AND qt_mock_data IS NOT NULL
  9  ORDER BY date1 DESC;
   WHERE     date1 >= '20220101'
             *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

## to my code

```
SQL> WITH test (date1, qt_mock_data) AS (SELECT '20220615', 'A' FROM DUAL)
  2    SELECT *
  3      FROM test
  4     WHERE     date1 >= '20220101'
  5           AND date1 BETWEEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1),
  6                                      'yyyymmdd')
  7                         AND TO_CHAR (
  8                                LAST_DAY (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1)),
  9                                'yyyymmdd')
 10           AND date1 != 'None'
 11           AND qt_mock_data IS NOT NULL
 12  ORDER BY date1 DESC;

DATE1    Q
-------- -
20220615 A

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your DB's schema. Maybe try using date literal?

```sql
WHERE 
  DATE >= date '20220101' 
  AND DATE BETWEEN add_months(
    trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 
    -1
  ) 
  AND last_day (
    add_months(
      trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 
      -1
    )
  ) 
  AND DATE != 'None' 
  AND QT_MOCK_DATA IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 
  DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not store dates as string, use a `DATE` data type (and do not use reserved words such as `DATE` as an identifier).

---

However, since you are storing the values as dates then convert the value you are comparing to to a string using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
WHERE "DATE" >= '20220101'
AND   "DATE" >= TO_CHAR(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1), 'YYYYMMDD')
AND   "DATE" <  TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate,'mm'), 'YYYYMMDD')
AND   "DATE" != 'None'
AND   QT_MOCK_DATA IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY "DATE" DESC
```

which can be simplified to:

```sql
WHERE "DATE" >= TO_CHAR(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1), 'YYYYMMDD')
AND   "DATE" <  TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate,'mm'), 'YYYYMMDD')
AND   QT_MOCK_DATA IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY "DATE" DESC
```

*(Since the start of the range will, assuming `SYSDATE` is not set to a past dates, always be greater than `20220101` and if the date range is valid then `!= 'None'` will always also be true.)*